# How to replace HTML tag in URLRequest Flex 4 / Air

Tags: javascript, html, apache-flex, air

I am embedding a website into my application, and Adobe Air does not recognize the breakline HTML tag in the source code (Firefox and Chrome auto-correct the error).  I have attached the source code below.  Is there a way to replace the breakline with the correct syntax (no forward slash).  I do not control the website, I am merely loading it into my application, so I can't just change it at the source.  I am using an mx:html object and htmlLoader to load the url.

Website Source:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="Rpt_Selection_2.asp?Report=StatusReport/StatusReport.asp">Status Report</a></li>
    <li><a href="Rpt_Selection_2.asp?Report=StatusReport/AlarmsAlerts.asp">Alarm History</a></li>
</ul>

<br/>

<table class="Header" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
    <tr>
      <td class="HeaderLeft"><img src="Images/Spacer.gif" border="0"></td> 
      <th>List of&nbsp;Alarms for Multiple Groups&nbsp;</th>
      <td class="HeaderRight"><img src="Images/Spacer.gif" border="0"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

mxml Component:

```
<mx:HTML  id="htmlControl" width="100%" height="100%"/>
```

Script to load URL:

```
htmlControl.htmlLoader.load(new URLRequest("http://mysite.com/somepage.asp"));
```

Thanks you.

Answer (score 1):

The way I've handled this in the past was to use a URLLoader to first retrieve the content, then modify it, then set the content into an HTML component by calling myHtmlComponent.htmlLoader.loadString(myModifiedContent)

Hope that helps.

EDIT: After reading the comment below, you may be having trouble with loading referenced scripts if they are referred to using a relative URL rather than the full URL.  I've fixed this in the past by prepending a base tag so the relative URLs can resolve properly.  After retrieving the content, and before calling myHtmlComponent.htmlLoader.loadString, prepend like so:

```
myModifiedContent = "<base href='http://mydomain.com/'/>" + myModifiedContent;
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Wade. I was able to get this to display the text and html (eg - forms) elements of the site, but the javascript or something is not working. The site is a user interface to a SQL server, could this be part of the issue? This is what I wrote:

`private var htmlControl:HTMLLoader = new HTMLLoader();`
`private var urlControl:URLLoader = new URLLoader();`
`urlControl.load(new URLRequest("http://site.com/page.asp"));`
`var strText:String = urlControl.data;`
`strText = removeHTMLTags(strText); //This does remove the tags fine`
`htmlControl.htmlLoader.loadString(strText);`

Comment: Hi Carter, I updated my answer to hopefully help with your issue.  Good luck.